# How to fix Exception:Failed to transmit in blackberry application development

Tags: java, networking, blackberry, connection

In my application i am using ksoap2 library and i got a exception: Failed to transmit when  application try to make connection via WAP2.0 transport in Argentina and Panama and in all other country application is working fine.

kindly provide me if is there any solution for the same any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you setting the transport type to the http connections? If you are doing it the old way (via suffixes in the URL), could you post an example?

Comment: HttpTransport httpTransport = new HttpTransport(requestURL+";ConnectionUID="+wapuid);
httpTransport.call(requestAction + soapMethod, envelope);
SoapPrimitive soap = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
response = soap.toString();                                            here i got exception: Failed to transmit

Comment: Exception got in Argentina and Panama, But it is working fine in other country.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has to do with the country, the devices probably have a different configuration.

First, you must check a service record with CID = "WPTCP" exists in the troubled devices. Check the UID is the one you are using. For WAP2, it should contain "WAP2".

Second, append the "deviceside" suffix to the URL to make sure it does not attempt to go through other connection mode:

```
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new HttpTransport(requestURL+";deviceside=true;ConnectionUID="+wapuid);
```

More info: [Different ways to make an HTTP or socket connection](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Different-ways-to-make-an-HTTP-or-socket-connection/ta-p/445879#6)

---

UPDATE:
Try this code in the troubled devices:

```
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setPreferredTransportTypes(new int[]{TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_WAP2});
    factory.setDisallowedTransportTypes(new int[]{TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_WAP, TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_BIS_B, TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_MDS, TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_WIFI, TRANSPORT_TCP_CELLULAR});

    ConnectionDescriptor cd = factory.getConnection("http://www.google.com");
    HttpConnection httpConnection = (HttpConnection) cd.getConnection();

    //Now work with httpConnection as usual.
```

If it does not work, then you can't open a WAP2 connection for some reason.

Comment: First of all, Thanks dude for your reply. Here i have checked all things which you have mentioned above. but still didn't get any solution.

Comment: You could code a small test app to open a regular http connection using WAP2, but without ksoap. Then test it in the devices with problems. If it worked, then the problem might be in ksoap, or in the way you are using it.

Comment: Yes, i have tested it in sample application still getting same problem on that device.

Comment: Looks like you can't open a WAP2 connection in those devices. I'd make a final test using the newer `ConnectionFactory` with WAP transport type.

Comment: Yes Smith you are right. kindly let me know whenever you have done.

Comment: is it depends on any particular career? because it works for some career in some countries but it doesn't work for some other career on other countries.

Comment: Yes. WAP is an old technology, which is being phased off. Main carriers in EU still support it, not sure about WAP 2.0. So yes, the carrier must support it, but also the user should have contracted it, and finally de device should be properly configured (it happens normally automatically). But you can always use a fallback transport type.